# Illegal Character in Query

Tags: java, android

In my Application, I'm able to run this method below with following code:

```
fahrtenStr = getHtml("http://myServer.com/abc/getFahrtenList.cgi?limit=15");
```

But If I try to use this version, to call the method, It doesen't work:

```
String url = "http://myServer.com/abc/insert_fahrt.cgi?values="+startKM+"x"+endKM+"x"+fahrer;
getHtml(url);
```

There I got the following error Message:

```
03-03 16:49:15.363: E/AndroidRuntime(21355): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 65: http://myServer.com/abc/insert_fahrt.cgi?values=11003.4
03-03 16:49:15.363: E/AndroidRuntime(21355): x111111xSimon
03-03 16:49:15.363: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
03-03 16:49:15.363: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
03-03 16:49:15.363: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):    at net.x.y.fahrtenbuch.Uebersicht.getHtml(Uebersicht.java:255)
03-03 16:49:15.363: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):    at net.x.y.fahrtenbuch.Uebersicht$3$1.run(Uebersicht.java:153)
```

my function:

```
    public String  getHtml(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    String result = "";

    BufferedReader reader = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        result += line + "\n";
        // Toast.makeText(Connect.this, line.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return result;
}
```

And finally my used variables:

```
//Variable values
    startKM: String="11003.4"
    endKM: String="11111"
    fahrer : "Simon"
```

Comment: It looks like you have a rogue newline

Comment: No, this was my Debugger... This is in one line...

Comment: "This is in one line" -- not according to the operating system, which is showing it split across two lines in LogCat.

Comment: It's hard to believe that it's one line when there are two error messages in the log. How is the value assigned to `startKM` being generated?

Comment: Oh yes, now I see. I downloaded this variable with this function and it added after each line a "\n". 
I removed it and now it works!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String url = "http://myServer.com/abc/insert_fahrt.cgi?values="+startKM+"x"+endKM+"x"+fahrer;
url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
getHtml(url);
```

Space is not work in the url
You may have space in your three variable (startKM,endKM,fahrer)
in url space must be replace with %20